# Hibernate Search: why .getResultsize is greater than .list().size()?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

The similar question was asked but not solved.
Here is my code

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(currentSession());
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
          .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Design.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
          .keyword()
          .onFields("designName", "description")
          .matching(text)
          .createQuery();
org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery hibQuery =
        fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Design.class);
hibQuery.setFirstResult(start);
hibQuery.setMaxResults(num);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Design> designList = hibQuery.list();
for (Design design : designList) {
     Hibernate.initialize(design.getDesignImages());
}
return designList;
```

Why hibQuery.list().size() is smaller than hibQuery.getResultSize(). Because of this difference, the .setMaxResults() does not work properly.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A reason for this can be that the index and database are not in sync at the time of querying. `getResultSize` is based on the Lucene query result size whereas `list.size()` is the actual size of materialized (loaded) entities.

Comment: Anything suggestion for solving this problem? When I .setMaxResults()  it does not limit the maximum result correctly.

Comment: What is your exact problem? What is your use case?